# What kind of pump do I need for my giant rain barrel?

Tags: vegetables, watering, rain-barrel

I have a giant rain barrel that holds 1,000 litres when filled. It was one of those industrial white cube barrels that are used for food. It was decommissioned and sold as a rain barrel. Anyhow, it's set up and has water in it. Instead of using water from the house I would like to use the water in the barrel to water my vegetable garden. I have several garden boxes that have soaker hoses running through them. I have a hose going from the house, under the ground (20 feet or so), to the garden where it then goes into a splitter to feed all the boxes.

I want to get a pump for the rain barrel that I can use for the watering but I am not sure how strong of a pump is needed. Do I need something like [this sump pump](https://www.canadiantire.ca/en/pdp/mastercraft-1-5-hp-submersible-utility-pump-0624146p.html), or is something like [this pond pump](https://www.homedepot.ca/product/algreen-products-500gph-pond-pump-for-water-gardening-and-water-features/1001010054) good enough? I've read that soaker hose needs at least 10 psi for the water to come out, but I would like something that provides about the same pressure as I get from the house.

Answer (score 1):

You don't get pressure from either sump or pond pumps. A pond pump that puts out 20 ft. of head ( 10 psi) would be relatively high pressure . A home water pump would be most practical . It has been many decades since I bought one from Sears but it was relatively inexpensive. It is important not to let the pump run dry. There were small reciprocating pumps ( piston) which would be good but I doubt there are any made today. I have a 55 g rain barrel ;I use a small pond pump but basically is just siphons water to a lower area.

Comment: You mean like a pump that you have if you live in the country and use well water? What about [something like this](https://www.homedepot.ca/product/ecoflo-submersible-utility-pump-1-4hp/1001021551)?

Comment: No , those are pretty much sump pumps. You need a pump such as would be for a home well for pressure  like 40 psi.

Comment: Yuck. I am not buying one of those for a rain barrel. I just need something strong enough to push water out of the soaker hoses.